# Clojure - named arguments

Tags: clojure

Does Clojure have named arguments? If so, can you please provide a small example of it?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

In Clojure 1.2, you can destructure the `rest` argument just like you would destructure a map. This means you can do named non-positional keyword arguments. Here is an example:

```
user> (defn blah [& {:keys [key1 key2 key3]}] (str key1 key2 key3))
#'user/blah
user> (blah :key1 "Hai" :key2 " there" :key3 10)
"Hai there10"
user> (blah :key1 "Hai" :key2 " there")
"Hai there"
user> (defn blah [& {:keys [key1 key2 key3] :as everything}] everything)
#'user/blah
user> (blah :key1 "Hai" :key2 " there")
{:key2 " there", :key1 "Hai"}
```

*Anything* you can do while destructuring a Clojure map can be done in a function's argument list as shown above. Including using :or to define defaults for the arguments like this:

```
user> (defn blah [& {:keys [key1 key2 key3] :or {key3 10}}] (str key1 key2 key3))
#'user/blah
user> (blah :key1 "Hai" :key2 " there")
"Hai there10"
```

But this is in Clojure 1.2. Alternatively, in older versions, you can do this to simulate the same thing:

```
user> (defn blah [& rest] (let [{:keys [key1 key2 key3] :or {key3 10}} (apply hash-map rest)] (str key1 key2 key3)))
#'user/blah
user> (blah :key1 "Hai" :key2 " there")
"Hai there10"
```

and that works generally the same way.

And you can also have positional arguments that come before the keyword arguments:

```
user> (defn blah [x y & {:keys [key1 key2 key3] :or {key3 10}}] (str x y key1 key2 key3))
#'user/blah
user> (blah "x" "Y" :key1 "Hai" :key2 " there")
"xYHai there10"
```

These are not optional and have to be provided.

You can actually destructure the `rest` argument like you would any Clojure collection.

```
user> (defn blah [& [one two & more]] (str one two "and the rest: " more))
#'user/blah
user> (blah 1 2 "ressssssst")
"12and the rest: (\"ressssssst\")"
```

You can do this sort of thing even in Clojure 1.1. The map-style destructuring for keyword arguments only came in 1.2 though.

Answer (score 36):

In addition to Raynes' excellent answer, there is also [a macro in clojure-contrib](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/def-api.html#clojure.contrib.def/defnk) that makes life easier:

```
user=> (use '[clojure.contrib.def :only [defnk]])
nil
user=> (defnk foo [a b :c 8 :d 9] 
         [a b c d])
#'user/foo
user=> (foo 1 2)
[1 2 8 9]
user=> (foo 1 2 3)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No value supplied for key: 3 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
user=> (foo 1 2 :c 3)
[1 2 3 9]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that! I was all caught up in showing the 10 thousand ways Clojure can destructure stuff. :p

Comment: clojure-contrib is deprecated, and I couldn't find a current alternative. Any ideas?

Comment: @Lstor: check out [defnk](https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing/blob/7ae0e85e4921325b3c41ef035c798c29563736dd/src/plumbing/core.cljx#L470) in [prismatic/plumbing](https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing)

Answer (score 7):

As of Clojure version 1.8, keyword support still seems a bit *meh*.

You can specify keyword arguments like this:

```
(defn myfn1
  "Specifying keyword arguments without default values"
  [& {:keys [arg1 arg2]}]
  (list arg1 arg2))
```

Examples of calling it:

```
(myfn1 :arg1 23 :arg2 45)  --> evaluates to (23 45)
(myfn1 :arg1 22)           --> evaluates to (22 nil)
```

If you want to specify default values for these keyword arguments:

```
(defn myfn2
  "Another version, this time with default values specified"
  [& {:keys [arg1 arg2] :or {arg1 45 arg2 55}}]
  (list arg1 arg2))
```

This does the expected thing in the second case:

```
(myfn2 :arg1 22)           --> evaluates to (22 55)
```

There are pros and cons to each part of each language, but just for comparison, this is how you would do the same stuff in Common Lisp:

```
(defun myfn3
    (&key arg1 arg2)
    "Look Ma, keyword args!"
    (list arg1 arg2))

(defun myfn4
    (&key (arg1 45) (arg2 55))
    "Once again, with default values"
    (list arg1 arg2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps mean *named parameters*? These aren't directly available, but you can [use this vectors approach](https://web.archive.org/web/20101125040325/http://measuringmeasures.com/blog/2009/6/28/named-parameters-in-clojure.html) (web archive link) if you like, which may give you what you want. Copy of that example:

> Technically, in Clojure this is not really "named params" but how Clojure destructures maps passed into the parameter vector.
>
> ```
> user> (defn a [{b :b c :c}] (- b c))
> #'user/a
> user> (a {:c 5 :b 11})
> 6
> ```

[At RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Named_parameters#Clojure) there's a deeper explanation on how to do this using destructuring.

Quote (in case of linkrot):

> Clojure doesn't have built-in support for named or keyword arguments, but you can use destructuring to achieve a similar effect.
>
> ```
> (defn foo [& opts]   (let [opts (merge {:bar 1 :baz 2} (apply hash-map opts))
>     {:keys [bar baz]} opts]
> [bar baz]))
> ```
>
> Clojure 1.2 supports destructuring of trailing arguments as a map:
>
> ```
> (defn foo [& {:keys [bar baz] :or {bar 1, baz 2}}]   [bar baz])
> ```
>
> You can also use defnk from `clojure.contrib.def`, which is a macro that works similarly.
>
> ```
> (use 'clojure.contrib.def) (defnk foo [:bar 1 :baz 2]   [bar baz])
> ```
>
> Sample output for all variants:
>
> ```
> user> (foo :baz 123) [1 123]
> ```

Comment: @Abel Can you share the examples you link to? (They have a way of changing or getting out of date).

Comment: And now they are out of date.

Comment: @Terbiy and david you are right, I should have done that. Usually I do add inline examples. Not sure what I was thinking over a decade ago lol. Anyway, thanks to the wayback machine, it is all still there. Copied for posterity.