# Is there anything similar like ML's datatype declaration and pattern matching in clojure?

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching, ml

I'm new to both sml (1 month) and clojure(1 week).  I learned datatype and pattern matching in  sml weeks ago and want to know if there are anything similar in clojure.
There seems to be several pattern matching library out there. Do they have the full power of ML's pattern matching? 
How about datatype? Do I have to use something like deftype to create my own datatype? If so, how do I do it? deftype looks pretty complex to me.

If people don't use datatype in lisp world, then what is the idiomatic way to do pattern matching with datatype in clojure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure replacement for ADTs and Pattern Matching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541794/clojure-replacement-for-adts-and-pattern-matching)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Clojure world you have a few "a la carte" options for polymorphism that you can use:

- You would normally use [protocols](http://clojure.org/protocols) if you want to define efficiently dispatched functions that work polymorphically with different data types. Different data types can mean Java classes or Clojure types defined with `deftype` or `defrecord`.
- [core.match](https://github.com/clojure/core.match) is a pretty good general purpose pattern matching library
- [Multimethods](http://clojure.org/multimethods) provide general purpose polymorphic dispatch, that can dispatch/match on any function of their parameters. Slightly slower than protocols, but very flexible.

As for defining your own data types:

- Don't underestimate doing things with pure data (stored in regular maps, lists, vectors). In most cases, this is the easiest and most flexible approach in Clojure.
- If you decide that isn't enough, I'd suggest `defrecord` rather than `deftype` in most instances: defrecord creates something that behaves like a hashmap, so it is quite flexible and user friendly. deftype is more of a low-level construct for people writing libraries and compilers etc.