# Does anyone know of a good way to provide keyword arguments in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I would like to be able to call clojure functions using keyword arguments like this:

```
(do-something :arg1 1 :arg2 "Hello")
```

: Is this possible without having to do:

```
(do-something {:arg1 1 :arg2 "Hello"})
```

: and could I also use :pre pre-conditions to provide somse sort of validation to make sure all arguments are included?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clojure - named arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337888/clojure-named-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want default values for the keyword args do the following (Clojure 1.2):

```
(defn foo
  [req1 req2 & {:keys [opt1 opt2] :or {opt1 :hello opt2 :goodbye}}]
  [req1 req2 opt1 opt2])
#'user/foo
user=> (foo :a :b)
[:a :b :hello :goodbye]
user=> (foo :a :b :opt1 "xyz")
[:a :b "xyz" :goodbye]
```

Comment: Is :or part of the syntax or a second way of doing it?

Comment: @Zubair: `:or` is optional. If it is not provided, the arguments get the value null if they are missing: `(defn foo [req1 req2 & {:keys [opt1 opt2]}] [req1 req2 opt1 opt2]) (foo :a :b) => [:a :b nil nil]`

Answer (score 5):

Keyword args are provided by the built-in destructuring of rest args (though the [main docs for destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28let%20[bindings*%20]%20exprs*%29) unfortunately doesn't cover this addition in 1.2):

```
(defn foo
  [a b & {:keys [c d]}]
  [a b c d])
#'user/foo
(foo 1 2 :c 12 :d [1])
[1 2 12 [1]]
```

All of the usual map destructuring facilities are available (e.g. `:or`, `:strs`, `:syms`, etc).