# How can I use named parameters in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In clojure I can use defnk to get named parameters. How can I achieve the same thing in ClojureScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure - named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337888/clojure-named-arguments)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The named args functionality in ClojureScript is the same as in Clojure:

```
(defn f [x & {:keys [a b]}] 
  (println (str "a is " a " and b is " b)))

(f 1)
; a is  and b is 

(f 1 :a 42)
; a is 42 and b is 

(f 1 :a 42 :b 108)
; a is 42 and b is 108
```

If you want default values, then change the original to:

```
(defn f [x & {:keys [a b] :or {a 999 b 9}}]
  (println (str "a is " a " and b is " b)))

(f 1)
; a is 999 and b is 9
```

This is related to the nice answer for [Clojure - named arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337888/clojure-named-arguments)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now I'm really confused. Why has defnk been put into Clojure then?

Comment: There's no such thing in clojure by default. It may be included in clojure.contrib (don't know if it is), but such macro doesn't exist in standard clojure library.

Comment: `defnk` is defined in clojure.contrib. It was created before Clojure 1.2 added full map destructuring binding. `defnk` should now be considered obsolete (indeed the monolithic clojure.contrib isn't compatible with Clojure 1.3 going forward.)

Comment: is there a way to use a keyword argument like :do-logs and then use something like (when do-logs ...) within the body?